# Python character rotation

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

Could you please help me with writing a function, which receives a character char (ie., a string of length one ), and an integer rotation. My function should return a new string of length one, the resulting of rotating char by rotation number of places to the right. My output for this code should be like this:

```
print(alphabet_position(a, 13)) = Output = n
print(alphabet_position(A, 14)) = Output = (capital) O
print(alphabet_position(6, 13)) = Output = 6
```

My function looks like this

```
 def alphabet_position(letter, number):
    for char in letter:
        return ord(char)+ number
print(alphabet_position("g", 2))
print(alphabet_position("Z", 2))
```

The output is 105
The output is 92

Comment: What should `print(alphabet_position("Z", 2))` return? Is it "B"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You forgot to do the checks you have mentioned and also, you need to use the* `chr(returnedValue)` *to convert the returned integer to a character. Check out the below code for the function*:

```
def alphabet_position(letter, number):
    if len(letter) != 1:
        return -1 #Invalid input
    elif letter.isalpha() == False:
        return letter #If its not an alphabet
    else:
        ans = ord(letter) + number
        # the below if-statement makes sure the value does not overflow.
        if ans > ord('z') and letter.islower():
            ans = ans - ord('z') + ord('a')
        elif ans > ord('Z') and letter.isupper():  
            ans = ans - ord('Z') + ord('A')
        return chr(ans)
```

Comment: Your very welcome. If you liked my answer, please upvote it.

Comment: Thank you. I did check the function. The output is:                                             print(alphabet_position("a", 0))  = output should be a
print(alphabet_position("A", 13)) = output should be N
print(alphabet_position("a", 13)) = output should be n    But the output is H, N, U

Comment: Im sorry, your comment is incomprehensible.

Comment: I have fixed that now

Comment: Could you please suggest online python training. If possible, can you give your email?

Comment: I primarily learnt python from Derek Banas' youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4mEzFDjqtA) and checked out `http://www.learnpython.org/` site from time to time. As for my email, I am afraid I can not offer you personal information. You may of course contact me via StackOverflow Chat whenever you have a doubt.