# How to fix 'string index out of range' error in a function that ciphers a string

Tags: python, string, rot13

I don't know how to efficiently go back to the beginning of the alphabet, when  (index of a letter + 13) is out of range

I've written a function that only works if the (index of a letter + 13) is in range.

```
def rot13(message):
    letters = [i for i in message]
    for i in letters:
        if i.isupper():
            letters[letters.index(i)] = 
string.ascii_uppercase[string.ascii_uppercase.index(i) + 13]
        elif i.islower():
            letters[letters.index(i)] = 
string.ascii_lowercase[string.ascii_lowercase.index(i) + 13]
        else:
            continue
    return ''.join(letters)
```

When I call, e.g. rot13('Test'), of course I get the 'string index is out of range' error, how should i go about that problem?

Comment: What is the expected output in case of `Test` ?

Comment: 'Grfg' @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: Perhaps this might be of help too @hubvoy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558688/python-character-rotation

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulo operator `%`:

Modulo devides the number by the given factor and keeps the rest, eg:

```
27 % 26 = 1
```

In your case it would be this two lines:

```
string.ascii_uppercase[(string.ascii_uppercase.index(i) + 13) % 26]

string.ascii_lowercase[(string.ascii_uppercase.index(i) + 13) % 26]
```